# Short Sql query to merge rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

If I have this table:

```
Column1 Column2     Column3 
20          NULL     3/27/2012 
NULL        50      3/27/2012
NULL        40      3/27/2012
```

How can I turn it into:

```
Column1 Column2     Column3 
20          90      3/27/2012
```

Thanks!

Comment: What results are you expecting when you have more than two rows for the same date?

Comment: for each date in column3, I need the sums on column1 and column2 for that respective date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT SUM(Column1) Column1, SUM(Column2) Column2, Column3
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Column3
```